# jQuery .on() with multiple selectors in event delegation?

Tags: jquery, delegates, live

I have using `.on()` in jQuery 1.7 and wondered whether it is possible to attach multiple selectors at a time for elements that have been injected onto a page. Previously, I was using `live()` - but it's obvious why I want to move given performance improvements.

Can you use `.on()` in the manner like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#selector1, #selector2, .class1', function () { 
     //stuff
});
```

And are there any benefits lost in attaching to document ?

?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. > Can you use .on() in the manner like:
   >
   > ```
   > $(document).on('click', '#selector1, #selector2, .class1', function () { 
   >     //stuff
   > });
   > ```

   [Yes, that will work.](http://jsfiddle.net/DDu3z/)
2. > I want to use this instead of `live()` given performance improvements.

   There are **no** performance advantages of using that code snippet as opposed to using `live()`, as `live()` itself binds events to the document, and in jQuery 1.7, live calls `on` behind the scenes.
3. > And are there any benefits lost in attaching to document?

   The downside to binding to `document` is that the event must traverse the entire list of ancestors before it is handled; this, [as pointed out in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/), is the slowest possible route. It will be better to handle to event sooner, by attaching the handler to an element closer to the source of the event.

Comment: right cool thanks. i suspected as much :) So basically, I just need to add a selector closer to where my `.on(` selectors are right ? i.e. something like `$('.closer-parent-container').on('click', '#selector1, #selector2, .class1',` ?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, exactly that. Obviously the element you call `.on()` on *must* be in the DOM at the time you call `.on()`.

Comment: @Matt - super! cleared up that for me in a jiff :) I'll select your answer when the timer allows me :) Thanks heaps!

Comment: @Matt - just lastly. Is there any way to easily deal with `$(this)` in the sense I want to target `#selector1, #selector2, .class1` as opposed to the `.closer-parent-container` ? using `$(this)` now selects `.closer-parent-container` instead of what I want - `#selector1, #selector2, .class1` ?

Comment: @Andy, that shouldn't be the case; see http://jsfiddle.net/DDu3z/1/. If you check the console upon clicking any of the elements, you'll see the correct output being reported. Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: @Matt - brain fart. Yep, totally with it now :) I need coffee :P - thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

it's possible and "this" is the clicked selector, not the document.

you better off attaching to the closest parent element of your selector. When you click on '#selector1', the event bubble up to the event handler element, here: document.

The more layers, the more actions. Moreover, if between selector1 and document there is another click event handler, it can be intercepted with `event.stopPropagation();`, and never reach the "document" event handler.

you can check the rogue event "interception" [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUzEr/).