# Object doesn't support property or method 'live'

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In MVC ..I have upgraded my Version to Jquery 1.9.1 and removed old versions .There is also no duplicate call in my JQuery ..I also Replaced live with on in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js ...Still this Error Continiues ..

**Edit** :
1.this error is coming on the same position on where I have replaced the first live Function ..
2.I have also restarted Asp.Net Server ..and clear all the Cache ..Still the Problem

**Edit 2:** I have Sort out this Problem By using old version of JQuery (1.5.2) ..I cannot change the whole project live function ...But there is Only One Problem Left that Tabs() function cannot be used in JQuery 1.5.2 ...I need sugesstion that if is there is any older version of Tabs()

Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/home.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/nivo-slider.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/jquery.multiselect.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/assets/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/assets/prettify.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/common/jquery.jqGrid-4.5.4/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/common/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/bootstrap-cerulean.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/assets/prettify.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/common/jquery.multiselect.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/fonts.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/highcharts/highcharts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/dashboard/eut.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/common/jquery/jquery.stickytableheaders.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/dashboard/ActRate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/dashboard/Zilla.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/dashboard/Fmi.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/dashboard/scores.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/dashboard/UFZillaErrorStatus.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/common/date.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/common/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/common/jquery/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

partial View(IndiaOCR.cshtml)

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "IndiaOCR_View";
}
<h2>
    IndiaOCR_View</h2>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li id="redi" runat="server" visible="true" class='selected'>@Ajax.ActionLink("maindiv", "maindiv", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "maindiv1" }, new { })</li>
            <li id="eutset" runat="server" visible="true">@Html.ActionLink("EUT", "EUT")</li>
            <li id="Li1" runat="server" visible="true">@Html.ActionLink("Regional Readiness", "RR")</li>
            <li id="Li2" runat="server" visible="true">@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Reports")Reports</li>
            <li id="Li4" visible="false">@Html.ActionLink("Settings", "Settings")</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="maindiv1">
            <p>
                maindiv</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    @using System.Web.Optimization
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#tabs").css({ 'color': "#444433", 'font-family': "Nokia Sans Wide Multiscript, Arial, sans-serif", 'font-size': "1em" });
            $("#tabs").tabs();

            var als = $('#tabs a[href="#maindiv"]').parent().index();
            $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", als);
            //var disabled = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'disabled');
            //$("#tabs").tabs('option', 'disabled', [3, 4]);
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {

                    if (ui.newTab.index('option', 'selected') != ui.newTab.index()) {

                        window.open($(ui.newTab).find('a').attr('href'), '_parent');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#gmenu").css({ 'color': "#444433", 'font-family': "Nokia Sans Wide Multiscript, Arial, sans-serif", 'font-size': "1em" });
            $("#gmenu").tabs();
            //selected = $("#maindiv").text();




            $('.editbut').button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-pencil"
                },
                text: false



            });




        });
    </script>
</body>
```

My jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

```js
/*!
** Unobtrusive Ajax support library for jQuery
** Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
*/

/*jslint white: true, browser: true, onevar: true, undef: true, nomen: true, eqeqeq: true, plusplus: true, bitwise: true, regexp: true, newcap: true, immed: true, strict: false */
/*global window: false, jQuery: false */

(function ($) {
    var data_click = "unobtrusiveAjaxClick",
        data_validation = "unobtrusiveValidation";

    function getFunction(code, argNames) {
        var fn = window, parts = (code || "").split(".");
        while (fn && parts.length) {
            fn = fn[parts.shift()];
        }
        if (typeof (fn) === "function") {
            return fn;
        }
        argNames.push(code);
        return Function.constructor.apply(null, argNames);
    }

    function isMethodProxySafe(method) {
        return method === "GET" || method === "POST";
    }

    function asyncOnBeforeSend(xhr, method) {
        if (!isMethodProxySafe(method)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", method);
        }
    }

    function asyncOnSuccess(element, data, contentType) {
        var mode;

        if (contentType.indexOf("application/x-javascript") !== -1) {  // jQuery already executes JavaScript for us
            return;
        }

        mode = (element.getAttribute("data-ajax-mode") || "").toUpperCase();
        $(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-update")).each(function (i, update) {
            var top;

            switch (mode) {
            case "BEFORE":
                top = update.firstChild;
                $("<div />").html(data).contents().each(function () {
                    update.insertBefore(this, top);
                });
                break;
            case "AFTER":
                $("<div />").html(data).contents().each(function () {
                    update.appendChild(this);
                });
                break;
            default:
                $(update).html(data);
                break;
            }
        });
    }

    function asyncRequest(element, options) {
        var confirm, loading, method, duration;

        confirm = element.getAttribute("data-ajax-confirm");
        if (confirm && !window.confirm(confirm)) {
            return;
        }

        loading = $(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading"));
        duration = element.getAttribute("data-ajax-loading-duration") || 0;

        $.extend(options, {
            type: element.getAttribute("data-ajax-method") || undefined,
            url: element.getAttribute("data-ajax-url") || undefined,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                var result;
                asyncOnBeforeSend(xhr, method);
                result = getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-begin"), ["xhr"]).apply(this, arguments);
                if (result !== false) {
                    loading.show(duration);
                }
                return result;
            },
            complete: function () {
                loading.hide(duration);
                getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-complete"), ["xhr", "status"]).apply(this, arguments);
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                asyncOnSuccess(element, data, xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") || "text/html");
                getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-success"), ["data", "status", "xhr"]).apply(this, arguments);
            },
            error: getFunction(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-failure"), ["xhr", "status", "error"])
        });

        options.data.push({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" });

        method = options.type.toUpperCase();
        if (!isMethodProxySafe(method)) {
            options.type = "POST";
            options.data.push({ name: "X-HTTP-Method-Override", value: method });
        }

        $.ajax(options);
    }

    function validate(form) {
        var validationInfo = $(form).data(data_validation);
        return !validationInfo || !validationInfo.validate || validationInfo.validate();
    }

    $("a[data-ajax=true]").on("click", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.href,
            type: "GET",
            data: []
        });
    });

    $("form[data-ajax=true] input[type=image]").on("click", function (evt) {
        var name = evt.target.name,
            $target = $(evt.target),
            form = $target.parents("form")[0],
            offset = $target.offset();

        $(form).data(data_click, [
            { name: name + ".x", value: Math.round(evt.pageX - offset.left) },
            { name: name + ".y", value: Math.round(evt.pageY - offset.top) }
        ]);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(form).removeData(data_click);
        }, 0);
    });

    $("form[data-ajax=true] :submit").on("click", function (evt) {
        var name = evt.target.name,
            form = $(evt.target).parents("form")[0];

        $(form).data(data_click, name ? [{ name: name, value: evt.target.value }] : []);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(form).removeData(data_click);
        }, 0);
    });

    $("form[data-ajax=true]").on("submit", function (evt) {
        var clickInfo = $(this).data(data_click) || [];
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (!validate(this)) {
            return;
        }
        asyncRequest(this, {
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method || "GET",
            data: clickInfo.concat($(this).serializeArray())
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Please SUggest where I am missing

Comment: .live is deprecated in jquery 1.7.2 use .on()

Comment: You say you replaced `live()` in your ajax script, but what about everywhere else?  Does it tell you where the error is?

Comment: 1.this error is coming on the same position on where I have replaced the first live Function ..I have searched the solution ..there is No live function found 

2.I have also restarted Asp.Net Server ..and clear all the Cache ..Still the Problem

Comment: you might have problems with files caching on your server (not the browser cache), it would be great if you could reproduce the problem e.g. [here](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I have Sort out this Problem By using old version of JQuery (1.5.2) ..I cannot change the whole project live function ...But there is Only One Problem Left that Tabs() function cannot be used in JQuery 1.5.2 ...I need sugesstion that if is there is any older version of Tabs()

Comment: if you mean tabs from `jqueryui`, you should use jqueryui version that supports that version of jquery, e.g. you are using jqueryui 1.10, which only supports jquery 1.6 and newer see [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/), so I guess you should take jqueryui 1.8 which supports 1.3.2 and higher - see [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/)

Answer (score 6):

`.live()` has been deprecated in jq1.7 . You need to use `.on()` instead of `.live()`.

Also you nee to handle event delegation in different way while using `.on()`.

**[See The Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125436/1719752)**

Comment: _"I also Replaced live with on in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"_ - should be question about that statement, not an answer.

Comment: @Archer: It wont work by just replacing live with on if he is working with dynamically added dom.

Comment: Of course it won't, but you don't know what he did.  Sorry, but jumping to answer when you have little knowledge of the problem just strikes me as more interested in points than actually helping.

Comment: I do not think of any other issue in this case.

Comment: If you look at the script that he tells us he modified to use `on()` instead of `live()` then you can see that he is using it correctly and has nothing to do with delegation.  Also, the error message is about something trying to use `live()`, so again, nothing to do with delegation.

Comment: @Archer: he's using it correctly, but without events delegation, actually none of his `on` usages would work for dynamic content

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the posted code.  Why are people assuming this has anything to do with event delegation when the error message is about the use of `live()`???

Comment: @Archer: because `live` is intended to work with content added dynamically, the only way to make it work with new jquery is using delegeted events

Comment: Seriously, people need to read things before posting.  Please explain to me how incorrectly using `on()` will return the error message _Object doesn't support property or method 'live'_

Comment: Incidentally, delegation is a *feature* of `live()`, just like it is with `on()`.  Use of `live()` in no way means delegation is involved.

Comment: its not incidentally, it was the only reason for using `live` rather than `bind`

Comment: Yes, but it does not *mean* delegation.  Please read the question again as it has **nothing** to do with delegation.  The title of the question alone proves that fact beyond any doubt.

Comment: but title is not the onl;y information given, isn't it?

Comment: OMG!!! You read the documents.  Yes, `live()` *CAN* be used for event delegation, but it does not *MEAN THAT IT IS*!!!  Learn to ask questions in the comments section under the OP before jumping to incorrect conclusions and wasting the OP's and your own time.  This question has *NOTHING* to do with event delegation!!!  Seriously, I'm out of this.  I will not comment again, other than to the OP if they respond.