# jQuery selectors are returning same values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading values from two drop down menus and if in case none of them is not empty doing some stuff with it. Currently, despite having two different id's click option would work for 1 menu only and upon selection it sends the same value in both variables i.e."selectedAccuracy " and "selectedCountry ". 
Possibly I am doing something wrong with the selectors.

```js
$(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'server.php',
    data: {
      request_type: "get2",
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
      var selectList = document.createElement("select");
      selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
      myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

      for (var i = 0; i < (data.coordinates).length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", data.coordinates[i].Place);
        //console.log(data.coordinates[i].Place);
        option.text = data.coordinates[i].Place;
        selectList.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'server.php',
    data: {
      request_type: "get3",
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv1");
      var selectList = document.createElement("select");
      selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect1");
      myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

      for (var i = 0; i < (data.coordinates).length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", data.coordinates[i].level);
        //console.log(data.coordinates[i].level);
        option.text = data.coordinates[i].level;
        selectList.appendChild(option);
      }
    }
  });

  $('body').on('click', '#mySelect', '#mySelect1', function markers() {
    if ($('#mySelect').val() != '' && $('#mySelect1').val() != '') {
      move();
      initMap();
      var selectedAccuracy = $(this).val();
      console.log(selectedAccuracy);
      var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
      console.log(selectedCountry);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'server.php',
        data: {
          request_type: "get5",
          accuracy: selectedAccuracy,
          country: selectedCountry
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);

          var locations = parseLocation(data);
          var icons = parseIcons(data);
          addMarkers(icons, data, map);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .on() with multiple selectors in event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125384/jquery-on-with-multiple-selectors-in-event-delegation)

Comment: your selectors need to be in the same quotes and separated by commas

Comment: Also as a side note, given that this question is about the selector, most of this logic provided is unnecessary to replicate the problem.

Comment: Change `'#mySelect', '#mySelect1'` to `'#mySelect, #mySelect1'`

Comment: @Pete it woks this way. but when i click on the option of 1 drop down menu so it does not wait for to choose second option from another drop down menu. It is taking just one click to get values from both menus.